# Workaround for Invalid search provider URL that is not owned by the developer when site is hosted in Webflow

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, webflow

I want to redirect the user to my search engine. The website used in the search URL is hosted in Webflow.

The problem is Webflow's images are hosted in CDN so they have a different domain than my site domain. And so when I add the favicon URL using the link from Webflow it returns an error when I submit the extension.

*"The manifest has an invalid search provider URL that is not owned by the developer".*

Is there any workaround for this issue?

manifest.json

```
"chrome_settings_overrides": {
  "search_provider": {
     "encoding": "UTF-8",
     "favicon_url": "https://assets-global.website-files.com/12345/12345_favicon.png",
     "is_default": true,
     "keyword": "md",
     "name": "Search MD",
     "search_url": "https://my-domain.site/search/?q={searchKeyword}"
  }
```

},